# How to debug Liferay portlet using IntelliJ idea?

Tags: intellij-idea, liferay, remote-debugging

I deploy my application using Maven on Liferay 7 (on Tomcat 8). But I need to debug it. How to configure my debug? Because, when I start maven with debug mode, it builds and stops. I have no ideas how to deal with it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maven with debug mode is only targeted to debug maven build processes. If you want to debug your portlet you should follow the next steps:

**Run** Menu Entry **> Edit Configurations > Add New Remote Configuration > Configure your host and debug port**

[image]

You have to check too that JPDA port is enabled your Tomcat (you can enable it in your startup.sh/startup.bat script adding **jpda** in the final line)

```
exec "$PRGDIR"/"$EXECUTABLE" jpda start "$@"
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick generic answer (someone with actual IntelliJ experience can probably give more details):

You start tomcat, that has Liferay deployed. Follow the advice you have for "how to debug tomcat applications". The caveat is that you might need to point IntelliJ to the source files for some (all) of the modules in Liferay - which is a huge task (being composed out of 500 modules. For eclipse I'm [aware of a fix](https://web.liferay.com/en/web/jorge.diaz/blog/-/blogs/debugging-liferay-7-0-generate-modules-classpath-in-eclipse-using-generate_modules_classpath-sh), for IntelliJ I'm not aware. I'm pretty sure such a beast exists though.

It will be easier (e.g. quick) if you only need your own modules' source.